# Laravel 5.2: How to scheduled Command multiple times in a day

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.2 commands via scheduler, i can call the command by following code:

```
$schedule->command('command:name')
                ->dailyAt('08:55');
```

but now i want to call above command daily at six different times i.e. 8:45, 9:15, 9:45,10:15 etc

```
$schedule->command('command:name')
            ->when(function(){return true;});
```

Above code, with when function, isn't working somehow, can someone suggest best practices of laravel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Why not just define 4 tasks, it's simple and readable:

```
$schedule->command('command:name')->dailyAt('08:55');
$schedule->command('command:name')->dailyAt('09:15');
$schedule->command('command:name')->dailyAt('09:45');
$schedule->command('command:name')->dailyAt('10:15');
```

Also, you can put it in a loop:

```
foreach (['08:45', '09:15', '09:45', '10:15'] as $time) {
    $schedule->command('command:name')->dailyAt($time);
}
```

Comment: is this the only way, don't think this is a best practice.

Comment: @AwnAli there are better ways for intervals like `every 15 minutes`. I've just looked into the source code of the `dailyAt()` and similar methods and I don't see any better solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i'm just looking for better solution if there is any.

Comment: @AwnAli I don't think there is any. I've updated my answer with a more concise solution, but still, I like the first one better.

Comment: I like the foreach one, it better follows DRY.

Answer (score 8):

For Laravel 5.5 there's the `between()` function.  It's [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#defining-schedules)

```
$schedule ->command('foo')
          ->everyThirtyMinutes()
          ->between('8:45', '10:15');
```

Granted that won't do you for Laravel 5.2, but I'm sure you could do something with the `when()` function, as that is also [documented for v5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling#defining-schedules)

```
$schedule ->command('foo')
          ->everyThirtyMinutes()
          ->when(function () {
              return date('H') >= 8 && date('H') <= 11;
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cron to setup custom time;

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Example: 9am, 1pm and 5pm daily from Monday to Friday

```
foreach (['0 9 * * 1-5', '0 13 * * 1-5', '0 17 * * 1-5'] as $time) {
        $schedule->command('command:name')->cron($time);
    }
```

you can use https://crontab.guru to get the custom times accurately.